# Receiving HTTP ERROR with Django Uploadify S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am using [Django Uplodify S3](https://github.com/sbc/django-uploadify-s3) and I am having issues getting it to work. Files start to upload (progress is shown), then they just either pause indefinitely or result in a 'Http Error'.

My python code is pretty much identical to the example code given. I am running this on my local machine with the dev server.

I keep getting HTTP error 400, Amazon is reporting that there are extra fields in the POST request that I have not specified in my policy.

After looking at the link mouad provided, I made some changes to my policy to try and include all the files I should be, but I am not sure if I have declared them properly as the documentation for the Django Uploadfiy module is a bit unclear. Here's what I have:

```
@render
def upload_example(request, object_id):

    options = {"onError":"function (a,b,c,d) {alert('Error: '+d.type+'      Info: '+d.info)} "}
    key_pattern = 'example-%s/${filename}' % object_id
    post_data={
        'key': key_pattern,
        'success_action_status': "201",
        "starts-with": object_id
        }

    #
    # S3 uses conditions to validate the upload data. DUS3 automatically constructs
    # and includes conditions for most of the elements that will be sent to S3, but you 
    # need to pass in conditions for:
    #   - 'key', whose value changes at upload time. Note that the condition's value
    #     must correspond to the key pattern set above.
    #   - any extra elements set at upload time
    #
    # See the DUS3 README for more information on the conditions mapping:
    #   https://github.com/sbc/django-uploadify-s3
    #

    conditions={
        'key': {    'op': 'starts-with',
                    'value': ["$Filename", "$folder", "$key", "$Filedata", "$starts-with", "$Upload"], }
        }

    uploadify_options = uploadify_s3.UploadifyS3(
                            uploadify_options = options,
                            post_data=post_data, 
                            conditions=conditions
                            ).get_options_json()

    return ['s3.html', {"opt": uploadify_options}]
```

The part I am most concerned about is `'key', whose value changes at upload time. Note that the condition's value`. I am not sure how I should be declaring the value of `key`. The documentation is not very clear at all.

And then here is the error log from Amazon:

```
7654158c29cb89182a7a8836253c91d61945e514e4a738ee1f502eda245f71e0 joshhunttest [08/Jun/2011:05:24:34 +0000] 137.166.55.199 - 8212E79B67E4469F REST.GET.OBJECT crossdomain.xml "GET /crossdomain.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - 215 215 199 198 "http://localhost:8000/static/uploadify/uploadify.swf" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.10 Safari/535.1" -

7654158c29cb89182a7a8836253c91d61945e514e4a738ee1f502eda245f71e0 joshhunttest [08/Jun/2011:05:24:35 +0000] 137.166.55.199 - FDA8CED6EF7C3A19 REST.POST.BUCKET  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 MaxPostPreDataLengthExceeded 360 - 1010 - "-" "Adobe Flash Player 10" -
```

Comment: Have you checked error details contained in Amazon's response? That may help locate a problem.

Comment: Ahh good one. Amazon is saying "MaxPostPreDataLengthExceeded", but I wouldnt know what to do with that (nor what would cause it)

Comment: Does [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=49391) help? You have "file_upload" instead of "file". See the [sample html](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1).

Comment: Catch using Wireshark the http traffic of correct and wrong upload and compare it checking requests and responses.

Comment: Daniel, unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Did you check this post : http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/1416/#p5436 it has a long discussion about how to make uploadify work with s3, i guess that the error that you have is because as mentioned in the link, uploadify sends 3 more params to the server so you need to add them in your policy.

Comment: Are you sure is not some CSRF issue? When I used it I had to disable CSRF verification on the upload function.

Comment: The file isnt even getting to Amazon S3. Amazon is throwing me errors, not django

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but have you tried renaming the field from `file_upload` to `file`?

Comment: Is that all the code? pretty sure that should be more, like includes.

Comment: I'm using the Django uploadify S3 library which takes care of all of that. The includes is just to the standard uploadify library which has nothing (directly) to do with S3

Answer (score 0):

I believe your upload needs to be changed from 'filedata' to be named 'file'.

Take a look here for sample code:
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1092&categoryID=47